# Identifier is undefined using structs

Tags: c, struct

Just a (hopefully) quick and simple question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm working on a project and this code was given to us by the instructor and I can't for the life of me figure out why the compiler thinks `PartitionTableEntry` is undefined when it exists right above it in the code.

```
struct PartitionTableEntry
{
    unsigned char bootFlag;
    unsigned char CHSBegin[3];
    unsigned char typeCode;
    unsigned char CHSEnd[3];
    unsigned int LBABegin;
    unsigned int LBAEnd;
};

struct MBRStruct
{
    unsigned char bootCode[446];
    PartitionTableEntry part1;   // These lines
    PartitionTableEntry part2;   // right here
    PartitionTableEntry part3;   // is where the
    PartitionTableEntry part4;   // issue is
    unsigned short flag;
} MBR;
```

I'm not too savvy with C so there's probably something simple I'm missing so that's why I am turning to SO. I was told I could just drop this into my code from the instructor and it would work. Hopefully someone can figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're coding in C, not C++.  You've defined a type `struct PartitionTableEntry`; you've not defined a type `PartitionTableEntry`, so the compiler complains.

The story would be different in C++, but you aren't coding in C++.

To fix this, you could add `typedef struct PartitionTableEntry PartitionTableEntry;` before you start defining `struct MBRStruct`, or you can use `struct PartitionTableEntry` inside `struct MBRStruct`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This is what I meant when I thought I might be missing something obvious since I am not well versed in C. Thank you so much! I will accept this answer once the timer is up.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 It might be easier to use the common style of always keeping struct typedefs and struct variables separated. That is: `typedef struct { ... } MBRStruct;` ... `MBRStruct MBR;`